# Error connecting to Windows 2K3 server over remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

I have a Windows 2003 server that gives the following error every time I try to connect over remote desktop:

```
The system cannot log you on due to the following error: 
The specified domain either does not exist of could not be contacted.

Please try again or consult your system administrator.
```

What is the most likely cause of this?

Connecting to domain accounts on this server over the console* works normally.

*In this case the VMWare console

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to authenticate with the wrong domain information.  Try putting in YOURDOMAIN\username in the username field.

Comment: Aside from the fact that the domain drop down box prevents typos pretty well, this doesn't try to explain why login works from the console but not the remote desktop.